# Why does ExtractTextPlugin.extract produce an "__webpack_require__(...) is not a function" error

Tags: webpack, extract-text-plugin

I have what should be a fairly standard Webpack rule to suppose SASS files:

```
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                  fallback: 'style-loader',
                  use: [
                      {
                          loader: 'css-loader',
                          options: {
                              minimize: isProduction,
                              sourceMap: true,
                              importLoaders: 1
                          },
                      },
                    {
                      loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                          sourceMap: true,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                      loader: 'postcss-loader',
                      options: {
                          sourceMap: !!isProduction,
                          config: {
                              path: './postcss.config.js'
                          }
                      }
                  },
                ],
              })
      },
```

However this seems to produce an error:

```
Module build failed: TypeError: __webpack_require__(...) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--2-2!/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js!/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--2-4!/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js??ref--2-5!/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/packages/display-site/src/assets/styles/curvetips.scss:102:50)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--2-2!/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js!/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--2-4!/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js??ref--2-5!/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/packages/display-site/src/assets/styles/curvetips.scss:22:30)
    at module.exports.module.exports (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--2-2!/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js!/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--2-4!/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js??ref--2-5!/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/packages/display-site/src/assets/styles/curvetips.scss:65:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--2-2!/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js!/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--2-4!/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js??ref--2-5!/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/packages/display-site/src/assets/styles/curvetips.scss:68:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.exec (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:129:12)
    at /Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/loader.js:131:26
    at compile (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:300:11)
    at applyPluginsAsync.err (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:510:14)
    at next (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:202:11)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/loader.js:112:7)
    at next (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:204:14)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/src/instance.ts:442:13)
    at next (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:204:14)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/webpack/lib/CachePlugin.js:78:5)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:206:13)
    at compilation.seal.err (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:507:11)
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:195:46)
    at self.applyPluginsAsync.err (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:680:19)
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:195:46)
    at self.applyPluginsAsync.err (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:671:11)
    at next (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:202:11)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:244:6)
    at next (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:204:14)
    at Compilation.compilation.plugin (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/webpack/lib/BannerPlugin.js:67:5)
    at next (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:204:14)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:244:6)
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:206:13)
    at self.applyPluginsAsync.err (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:666:10)
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/Users/wichert/CurveTips/ws/display/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:195:46)
```

Removing the ExtractTextPlugin.extract call and using my list of loaders directly works fine, which makes me suspect there is something I am missing in ExtractTextPlugin.extract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your webpack to version 3.6.0. It is works for me!

`"devDependencies": {
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^2.3.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "6.0.45",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.0.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.4.1",
    "css-loader": "0.26.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.16.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "rimraf": "2.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "0.20.2",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "^3.6.2",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "tslint": "5.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.9.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^3.0.0"
  }`